# Call to jQuery next() not returning the nextSibling object

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, nextsibling

My document contains a text node with a span node after it. In the Chrome inspector, the text node's nextSibling object is the span node. However, calling textnode.next() returns 0 objects. I'm not adding a selector to the next call and seemingly identical situations throughout the code all work as expected.

Here's what the relevant DOM tree looks like:

```
<span id="parent-node">
  some text
  <span id="sibling-node">the span's text</span>
  more text
</span>
```

Why would calling next() on the "some text" node not return the "sibling-node" span?

Comment: Selecting a textnode playing around with it is always problematic. Why don't you select the `span` directly if it has an id?

Comment: jQuery doesn't generally operate on text nodes.  It works on elements.  For example, `next()` skips right over text nodes and ignored them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/next/)...

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of ***DOM elements***, the `.next()` method allows us to search through the immediately following sibling of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

So according to the docs, it is expected that `.next()` is called from an *element* node, not just any node.

Calling from a text node isn't supported.

Comment: I wasn't aware text elements weren't part of the DOM. Thanks for the clarification. Is there an efficient fix? I can obviously call parent() and search for the text node and then get the next element in the sibling list, but that seems unnecessarily time consuming.

Comment: @Jack: They are part of the DOM, but they're not DOM elements. An "element" is specifically a Type 1 DOM node, while a text node is a Type 3 node. The fix would probably just be to use the native `nextSibling` instead of a jQuery method.